# find longest running uninterrupted series

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame that is built like this:

```
library(lubridate)

seq_date <- rep(seq.Date(from = dmy('01-01-2016'), to = dmy('05-01-2016'), by = 'day'), 3)

vec_a <- c(rep('a', 3), NA, 'a')
vec_b <- c(rep('b', 4), NA)
vec_c <- c(NA, rep('c', 2), NA, 'c')

demo_df <- data.frame(date = seq_date,
                      var = c(vec_a, vec_b, vec_c)) 

demo_df
         date  var
1  2016-01-01    a
2  2016-01-02    a
3  2016-01-03    a
4  2016-01-04 <NA>
5  2016-01-05    a
6  2016-01-01    b
7  2016-01-02    b
8  2016-01-03    b
9  2016-01-04    b
10 2016-01-05 <NA>
11 2016-01-01 <NA>
12 2016-01-02    c
13 2016-01-03    c
14 2016-01-04 <NA>
15 2016-01-05    c
```

What I would like to find out is the the longest running uninterrupted sequence for each `var`. The expected output should be something on the lines of:

```
a 3
b 4
c 2
```

Each of the three categories in `var` start and end on the same date and a series would always be broken by an `NA`. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(demo_df)`), grouped by the run-length-id of non-NA elements of 'var' and the 'var', get the count (`.N`), then with second `[]`, grouped by 'var', get the `max` specifying the 'i' with `is.na` or use `na.rm=TRUE` in `max`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(demo_df)[, .N, .(var, rleid(!is.na(var)))][!is.na(var), .(count = max(N)), var]
#    var count
#1:   a     3
#2:   b     4
#3:   c     2
```

---

If we need a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
demo_df %>% 
   count(grp = cumsum(is.na(var)), var)  %>%
   filter(!is.na(var)) %>% 
   group_by(var) %>%
   summarise(Count = max(n))
```

Comment: This solves the problem perfectly. Thank you. However I'm not too well versed with `data.table`. Can you explain your code to me or point me to resources that would do the same? A `dplyr` solution would be helpful as well.

Comment: @JashShah  Updated the post with some description

Comment: @JashShah added the dplyr

Comment: This is neat. Never knew this function exist. Thx!

Comment: @akrun is there a way to get the start and end dates of the longest continuous series as well?

The output should be `a (2016-01-01, 2016-01-03)` and so on.

Or should I ask a different question?

Comment: @JashShah You can do this by `demo_df %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(is.na(var)), var) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% filter(!is.na(var))  %>% group_by(var) %>% filter(n == max(n)) %>% summarise(start = first(date), end = last(date), Count = max(n))`